# RCU usage in Process context and softirq context

Tags: linux-kernel, spinlock, smp, rcu

I am learning the new RCU based lockless synchronization approach in the linux kernel.

I already have a Kernel module which maintains hash_table (kernel hash api).

Until now I was using `spin_lock_irqsave()` in order to synchronize process context code trying to modify this hash while it may be getting updated in the softirq context.

I realised that because of this I am curtailing the benifits of softirq as I am serializing the access to resource, when softirq are invented to do just that.

So, now I think RCU is the best suited mechanism for my scenario and I can use `hash_add_rcu` `hash_for_each_rcu` to take benefits of RCU.

However will this mechanism work correctly with updaters (writers) in process context concurrently accessing with writers in softirq context?

Comment: Take a look at https://lwn.net/Articles/522262/

Comment: RCU may synchronize readers wrt to **single writer**. For synchronize writers wrt themselves you need to use additional mechanisms (e.g., spinlocks).